# Where can I find stock index data going back since at least 1900 from many different countries?

Tags: finance

I also need fundamental data on the indices. I would like at least monthly data. I would like to use the data for backtesting. I'm aware there's problems with spreads and transactions costs with doing backtesting with that data.